# Função recursiva para finalizar uma lista

Tags: c, lista, recursão

Desejo fazer uma função recursiva para desalocar a memória de cada bloco da lista, porém quando imprimo ela após o uso da função, entra em loop e são printados endereços de memória quando peço para imprimir (o correto seria não imprimir nada).

> *Declaração na main:* no *lista;
>
> *Chamada na main:* finaliza_recursivo(&lista);
>
> no *lista é apenas um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento (bloco) da lista.

Abaixo duas versões da mesma função, as duas estão dando o mesmo problema:

> ***Main***

```
int main()
{
    no *ini; //é um ponteiro para um bloquinho (inicio da lista)
    elem x;
    int erro;

    cria(&ini);

    x = 2;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);
    x = 3;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);
    x = 8;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);

    imprimir(ini);

    finaliza_recursivo(&ini);

    return 0;
}
```

> ***Funções***

```
void cria(no **inicio)
{
    *inicio = NULL;
}

void finaliza_recursivo(no **inicio)
{
    no *P;

    P = *inicio;

    if(P != NULL)
        finaliza_recursivo(&P->prox);
    free(P);
}

void finaliza_recursivo(no **inicio)
{
    if(*inicio != NULL)
        finaliza_recursivo(&(*inicio)->prox);
    free(*inicio);
}
```

Comment: Só para esclarecer? Você está imprimindo após chamar essa função? Em geral recomenda-se que use um [Exemplo mínimo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sua lista é uma lista encadeada correto? Se você está alocando os nós usando como ponteiro. Por que está usando ponteiro de ponteiro? Se você fez `no *n = (no*) malloc(sizeof(no))` basta chamar `free(n)`.

Comment: Estava imprimindo apenas para ver se tinha desalocado a memória. Possuo uma outra versão não recursiva que está funcionando e após chamá-la e em seguida imprimir, não imprime nada. Já quando uso a recursiva, ao imprimir, ela imprime endereços aleatórios. @Kyllopardiun

Comment: O que eu passo ali como início é apenas um ponteiro para o primeiro nó da lista. Quero fazer ele percorrer a lista e ir desalocando cada nó quando chegar na condição de parada.  @Wakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de fazer `free()` o conteúdo da variável fica com um valor inválido.

Aconselho a substituires esse valor inválido por `NULL`.

```
void finaliza_recursivo(no **inicio)
{
    if(*inicio != NULL)
        finaliza_recursivo(&(*inicio)->prox);
    free(*inicio);
    *inicio = NULL; /* limpa valor inválido */
}
```

Suponho que o teu problema não esteja na função em que dizes.

Aqui vai uma versão completa do programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no {
  int data;
  struct no *prox;
};

void finaliza_recursivo(struct no **inicio) {
  if (*inicio != NULL) finaliza_recursivo(&(*inicio)->prox);
  free(*inicio);
  *inicio = NULL;
}

void cria(struct no **inicio) {
  *inicio = NULL;
}

void inserir (struct no **inicio, int *valor, int *erro) {
  struct no *tmp;
  tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
  *erro = 1; /* assume que vai haver erro */
  if (tmp != NULL) {
    *erro = 0; /* afinal nao houve erro */
    tmp->data = *valor;
    tmp->prox = *inicio;
    *inicio = tmp;
  }
}

void imprimir(struct no *inicio, const char *msg) {
  int empty = 1;
  if (msg) printf("%s:", msg);
  while (inicio) {
    printf(" %d", inicio->data);
    inicio = inicio->prox;
    empty = 0;
  }
  puts(empty ? " (lista vazia)" : "");
}

int main(void) {
    struct no *ini; /* e um ponteiro para um bloquinho (inicio da lista) */
    int x;
    int erro;

    cria(&ini);

    imprimir(ini, "recem criada");

    x = 2;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);
    imprimir(ini, "depois de inserir 2");
    x = 3;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);
    imprimir(ini, "depois de inserir 3");
    x = 8;
    inserir(&ini, &x, &erro);
    imprimir(ini, "depois de inserir 8");

    finaliza_recursivo(&ini);
    imprimir(ini, "depois de finaliza_recursivo");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Atualizei o código com essa linha, porém o programa trava quando chamo essa função. @pmg

Comment: @Giovani: ve a versão completa, que [funciona no ideone](http://ideone.com/4FeTOJ).

Comment: tudo funcionando, obrigado.